# how insert data into database custom table using custom module in model

Tags: module, magento-1, custom

I have created custom module and model but could not insert the data into database using the model please help how to do it

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <stallioni_vendorpage>
            <version>0.1.0    
        </stallioni_vendorpage>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <stallioni_vendorpage>
                <class>Stallioni_Vendorpage_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>vendorpage_resource</resourceModel>
            </stallioni_vendorpage>
            <vendorpage_resource>
                <class>Stallioni_Vendorpage_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <vendorpage>
                        <table>vendorpage</table>
                    </vendorpage>
                </entities>
            </vendorpage_resource>
          </models>
        <resources>
            <vendorpage_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Stallioni_Vendorpage</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </vendorpage_setup>
            <vendorpage_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </vendorpage_read>
            <vendorpage_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </vendorpage_write>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <vendorpage>
                <class>Stallioni_Vendorpage_Block</class>
            </vendorpage>
        </blocks>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <vendorpage>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>stallioni_vendorpage</module>
                    <frontName>vendorpage</frontName>
                </args>
            </vendorpage>
        </routers>
        <layout>
                <updates>
                    <vendorpage>
                        <file>vendorpage.xml</file>
                    </vendorpage>
                </updates>
            </layout>
    </frontend>

</config>
```

model resource code

```
 class Stallioni_Vendorpage_Model_Resource_Vendorpage extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('vendorpage/vendorpage','vendorpage_id');
        //$this->_blockGroup = 'vendorpage';
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the closing version tag in your config XML, but that might just be a typo when posting it here.

Your model and resource model namespace should be the same, only the resource model adds _resource to the end.

Currently your model alias is:

```
<models>
    <stallioni_vendorpage>
```

You should change it to:

```
<models>
    <vendorpage>
```

This way it will match the entity you're registering in your resource model.